# PHP mailer smtp setup with gmail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Hello guys I have stuck with this problem for a while now. I am trying to send mail from xampp. I have went through several solutions posted here but none of them seem to work still. kind of need someone to point me to the right direction.

so in my **php.ini**

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = user@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

I also have the **sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"** commented with a **;**

now in my **sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=user@gmail.com
auth_password=123456
force_sender=shadidhaque2014@gmail.com
```

P.s: I only have the above code in sendmail.ini
now for the php script I have something very simple:

```
$send=mail('rzs2009@yahoo.com', 'subject', 'blah blah blah');
                    if ($send) {
                        # code..
                        echo "yes";
                    }else
                    {
                        echo "no";
                    }
```

now everytime I try to run the program I get a no. So no email is being sent. Where might I be going wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the mail log files you have defined. That's what they're for!

Comment: You're going wrong by calling `mail()` yourself; it's a bad way to go. You've tagged this question as PHPMailer, but are not using it. [Get it here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), follow [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

> http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: Please don't link to obsolete documentation.